# How to prove that the arc of 60º equals the radius of the circle? What theorem should I use?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm studying trigonometry from a old book and when he is calculating the sine and cosine of 30º he reasons that we should take the chord of 60º and that by geometry it equals the radius therefore 2.sin30º = 1 and the 1/2 shows up.

I am having trouble to prove that the 60º measures 1 radius. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: it's not about arcs if it's about chords

Comment: I've added a image to better explain myself.

Comment: $\triangle OB'B$ is isosceles because $OB=OB'=\text{radius}\,$, and it has one angle of $60^\circ$ by construction, so it is equilateral.

Comment: haha SHAME ON ME! thank you dxiv.